# Solving inequality. $5(y-2)-3(y+4)\geq 2y-30$

Tags: inequality

I solved this inequality, but at the end I got that $8 \geq 0$. Did I did this right. What does this mean.

This is how I solved it:
$$
5(y-2)-3(y+4) \geq 2y-30\\
5y-10-3y-12 \geq 2y-30\\
2y-22 \geq 2y-30\\
2y-2y-22+30 \geq 0\\
8\geq0\\
$$

Did I did it right?

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: I guess there might be some typo in the question... Usually when some one ask you to solve some inequality with a variable it is actually asking domain of the variable in which the inequality is satisfied.. may be you should look at the original question again.. maybe you should the say this holds for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ if your question has no typo..

Comment: The question is pretty simple: Solve the inequality:

Comment: Its correct. You showed that your inequality is equivalent to always true one $8\ge 0$. It means that whole domain is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Solving" the inequality in here means finding the domain of the variable $y$ in which the inequality is satisfied. What you have done is true, and it means the inequality satisfies for all real (or complex) numbers $y$. By the way, you can use "\ge" to show "$\ge$" in latex.

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks!!!